# .desktop file not working

Tags: 14.04, .desktop

I have a .desktop file that contains these lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firestorm
Comment=Client for Online Virtual Worlds, such as Second Life
Exec=/home/deus/Programs/Firestorm_64bit/firestorm
Icon=/home/deus/Programs/Firestorm_64bit/firestorm_icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
TargetEnvironment=Unity
StartupWMClass=do-not-directly-run-firestorm-bin
Categories=Application;Network;
StartupNotify=true
```

I just re-installed **Ubuntu 14.04** before the reinstall this file worked just fine. Now it doesn't. I did set the exec property.

When I run it from terminal I get this:

```
deus@xxx:~/DesktopShortcuts$ ./firestorm.desktop 
./firestorm.desktop: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
./firestorm.desktop: line 3: for: command not found
./firestorm.desktop: line 10: Network: command not found
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: ... I don't want to run it by terminal... it doesn't run in nautilus.

Comment: OK, you didn't mention that. The only example usage I see is trying to run it from a terminal. Do the files that the .desktop is referencing exist? (/home/deus/Programs/Firestorm_64bit/firestorm, /home/deus/Programs/Firestorm_64bit/firestorm_icon.png). You could also try removing or commenting out the lines that start with TargetEnvironment= (I don't see this one [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html)) and maybe StartupWMClass=.

Comment: Here is something else referring to how TargetEnvironment= is deprecated (and may, in fact, be removed from the source, which would break any .desktop files using it) and OnlyShowIn=Unity should be used instead: http://markmail.org/message/eypvnff4bieqf5bj

Comment: @Githlar... Since we're talking about .desktop files, it's only natural to run them through the desktop. The reason I tried command line was to see what was the error. And show it to this forum.
I did the change you suggested but nothing changed. Also I mentioned that it worked before I re-install Ubuntu 14.04. The same file. I also checked the paths just in case, they are correct.

Comment: If you try to manually run the command that the .desktop launches, does it work? `/home/deus/Programs/Firestorm_64bit/firestorm`

Comment: That was the problem! Copy pasting the folder from a windows partition to the linux partition (because of re-install) probably changed the permissions for the file. So the problem wasn't the permissions of the .desktop file. It was the permissions of the executable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a desktop shortcut as an script, because the shell won't understand the command and it'll just try to execute line by line what's in the text file.

Try this:

```
gnome-open firestorm.desktop
```

If it doesn't work, it may be a problem of permissions. Try to do the file executable with:

```
chmod +x firestorm.desktop
```

or trought the properties menu that appears if you right click on the desktop file.

Comment: I did what you said and it just opens the file as text file with gedit.

Comment: Try with nautilus after you give it execute permissions.

Comment: If you can see the icon of your program in Nautilus, darent's solution should work

Comment: Command 'gnome-open' not found. How does my Files application run the file without gnome-open?