# .desktop file :line 1: [Desktop: command not found

Tags: 14.04, .desktop

What is wrong with my .desktop file ???

I wrote a simple c++ program for learning purposes and all is fine with this. I compiled with `g++` and got a .out file (thought the .out may be relevant).

So I thought why not make a launcher for it, this is it `menu.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Game
Exec=/home/mark/Documents/cpp/Game_menu_project/menu.out
Terminal=true
Name=Menu
```

At first it had a lot of options but after many errors this if what remains.

If I click it

```
There was an error launching the application
```

In a terminal

```
menu.desktop: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
```

I know the `exec` command is right because if I make a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash  
/home/mark/Documents/cpp/Game_menu_project/menu.out
```

It runs fine, so I changed the `exec` to run the `menu.sh`, same errors.

Other .desktops are running fine, I use one at boot to set up the display, works fine if I click it, whats going on ?

I have seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473101/desktop-file-not-working) and the one it is marked duplicate of, but believe my issue is diffrent as I don't want to run the `.desktop` in a terminal, I want my menu.out to open in a new terminal ( Thats what `Terminal=true` should do right ?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
Type=Game
```

is invalid. Replace it with

```
Type=Application
```

This should fix the error when clicking it.

You can't run a `.desktop` file from the shell.

Comment: Yes that work, I can't believe it, I was just blind to it after working on it for hours, Thanks.