# [Manual shortcut]Bad interpreter

Tags: shortcuts, sublime-text

I downloaded 64-bit(it's compatible with my system etc.) Sublime Text from their official website,extracted tar file and opened new folder.There wasn't install file but executable did.I created symbolic link() to `/usr/bin` by typing following line in terminal:
`sudo ln -s [path of original] /usr/bin/stext`  (here `stext` is my arbitrary name for link).
 Everything works ok(I checked this executable works fine), but after I created desktop shortcut manually(via text editor) and allowed execution by typing:

```
sudo chmod +x Sublime Text Editor.desktop
```

I had following problem:
(I also tried this with `sudo`) `./Subline Text Editor.desktop`
it tells me `bad interpreter:such file or directory doesn't exists`
Now here is what I entered at `.desktop` file:

```
#!usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/stext
Version=1.0
Type=application
Icon=/home/pc/Downloads/sublime_text_3/Icon/256x256/sublime-text.png
Name=Sublime Text Editor
Terminal=false
Categories=Application
```

Now, maybe I changed order of instructions or what?I assume that problem is (like it says) at the first line: bad interpreter instruction. I know that first line is important to tell program which interpreter should be used, but anyone knows which one is appropriate for this task?

So, I emphasize that editor works, but I wish shortcut on `Desktop` and to completely figure out how to create it MANUALLY.

Comment: One minor thing: `/usr/bin` is for software controlled by dpkg and APT. Manually installed software should go into `/usr/local/bin` so that it isn't potentially clobbered by dpkg or APT.

Comment: Next time consult [official desktop specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) or [nice page from ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/desktop_entries).

Answer (score 1):

You did it wrong.

The correct desktop file `Subline_Text_Editor.desktop` should contain only last lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/stext
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Icon=/home/pc/Downloads/sublime_text_3/Icon/256x256/sublime-text.png
Name=Sublime Text Editor
Terminal=false
Categories=Application
```

There is no need to have header line (`#!usr/bin/env xdg-open` in your case).

You do not need `sudo` to make it executable.

Answer (score -1):

Problem fixed!
1)  Instead of Type=application  there should be Type=Application
2)  We can not run .desktop file from terminal.

([.desktop file :line 1: [Desktop: command not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639624/desktop-file-line-1-desktop-command-not-found)) helped me so much.
@N0rbert That for last lines isn't true, I checked it: Name of .desktop file: "S T E.desktop" (with spaces), name inside code: "Sublime Text Editor"-this worked. But anyway, thank you for help.