# Spyder Desktop entry does not work

Tags: .desktop, spyder

I have an installation of Spyder via anaconda on Ubuntu 18.04 and also on Linux Mint 20. In both cases I don't get an entry in the launcher, even if I copy the `spyder.desktop` file that came with the installation into the path `~/.local/share/applications` and making it executable.

The Desktop Entry looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Name=Spyder
GenericName=Spyder
Comment=The Scientific Python Development Environment
Icon=spyder
TryExec=spyder
Exec=spyder %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/x-python;
Categories=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;
Keywords=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Spyder
```

Am I missing something? I took the advice of this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/473109/719400) and ran `gnome-open spyder.desktop`
from the directory, but no response.

Comment: Note Mint is not supported on this site but of course Ubuntu 18.04 is.

Comment: Hello, still having the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04 too. Any suggestions?